# Airflow - Is there a way to set a timeout for a job to be based on yesterday's run?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

Currently implementing airflow with timeout of 2 hours for jobs using

```
`    "execution_timeout": timedelta(hours=2)  # Default Task Execution Timeout
`
```

Was looking to try and set this to be 1.5-2.5x the previous run time if possible but was not sure if that was possible